# What is different between static member function and global function?

Tags: c++

What is different between static member function and global function?

```
void globalFunc()
{
}

class Test
{
  public:
    //In grammar side, object's not own this function
    static void staticFunc(); 
};
```

The static member function is global function but, it can classify with meaning 
and limit access range.

But i can not understand why the static member function's calling convention
is a [this call].

I understand that normal member function must be [this call] because it must need the caller object's address but, why the static member function has a this call convention? I think it does not need caller's address, because it is not object's
function.
Is there have any difference between static member function and global function? (Not in grammar side But also low side)

Comment: Sorry, `[this call]`?

Comment: A static member function can be called as if it were a non-static member function (that does not make `this` available in the function). A static member function can not be `extern "C"`. Formally that means that you cannot portably use it as a C callback, but few if any compilers have that impractical defaults.

Comment: Calling conventions are implementation defined. What implementation are you referring to?

Comment: It means the function calling convention which name is __thiscall.

Comment: There are two question. The title's question and the question about calling convention.

Comment: Biggest difference that static member function still has access to private data of the class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Static class functions can

- access private and protected static data members within a class.
- access private and protected static functions.
- access private and protected per-instance data members within a class *if the static function has an instance of the class*.
- access private and protected per-instance functions *if the static function has an instance of the class*.
- shadow functions of the same name in base classes.
- access protected data and functions in base classes.

Global non-friend functions can do none of those.

Comment: You should add that only STATIC members and functions  can be accessed.

Comment: @FilipRistic: Other too, but you have to provide instance of the class.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I updated the answer to say that a class static function would need an instance of the object.

Comment: @FilipRistic Nope, `void Test::staticFunc() { Test t; t.somePrivateStuff(); }`

Comment: but (global) `friend` functions can also do that.

Comment: @Jarod42 A static class function can also access private data in another class as long as the other class declares the first class a friend. So friendship doesn't make a difference whether the function is global or class static.

Comment: @Jarod42 You are right, but I meant about direct access

Comment: @LincolnMan: I meant What are the difference between `globalFunc` with friend of `Test`, and `Test::staticFunc` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 A global friend function can access all the same functions and data within a class that a class static function can. The only difference then is that a class static function can override base class functions of the same name. This is actually important for class specific new and delete operators - which are always static. How would the compiler know to call the correct new and delete operators? :-)

Comment: The term **override** is meaningless for a static member function. It shadows (if anything). Virtual functions can be overridden. I see that the OP has selected this answer as a solution, although it fails to answer *any* of the more concrete questions. That's would be weird outside of SO.

Comment: One more difference to add: static functions are bound to the class scoping, i.e. they can be private, for example, and not callable from outside - in contrast to global functions.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Private class static functions can be called from outside by **friend** functions.

Comment: @LincolnMan That requires an explicit definition of friend function. Besides being a questionable idea, it's an additional required mechanism (well, you can also hack the executable binary to override private accessor). The question is about comparison of global vs. static functions.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername *"The question is about comparison of global vs. static functions."* Really? That was the question I answered and look whose answer got chosen.

Comment: @LincolnMan That's very self-satisfactory argument. Unfortunately, it has no relation to my comment.